# Using sjp.glm to plot predicted probabilities for 1 predictor at 1 time

Tags: r, data-visualization, logistic-regression, sjplot

I am able to generate desired [plots](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjp.glm/) using the following codes:

```
sjp.glm(fit,type="prob")
sjp.glm(fit,type="eff")
sjp.glm(fit,type="y.pc")
```

However, I will like to plot the graphs separately instead of all in one. I've tried arguments like `var, vars, term and terms`, but none is working. I went through the [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/node/223822) but still can't locate the correct argument for my purpose.

Any idea or alternative on this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the argument `facet.grid = FALSE`? This option is not supported for all plot types in sjPlot version 1.9 - however, I'm planning to submit an update to CRAN this week, where I improved different plot types alot (see also [this news file](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel/blob/master/NEWS.md)).

Comment: Yes. I wanted to set `vars` as well along with `facet.grid=FALSE` to print individual plot at a time. Great to hear that the updates is coming! Looking forward for the improvements! Thank you!

Comment: [Please let me know if you need me to ask this as another new question] I noticed that if I build my logistic model using formula that contains `poly` will not work for certain sjPlot functions, I will get the following outputs:

Comment: `sjp.glm(fit,type="prob",show.ci=TRUE)
Error in '$<-.data.frame'('*tmp*', "xbeta", value = numeric(0)) : 
replacement has 0 rows, data has 81`

Comment: You can also file an issue at GitHub: https://github.com/sjPlot/devel/issues - and please provide a reproducible example.